# NodeJs Security - Read hashed sha256 password from DB

Tags: node.js, security, hash, amazon-web-services

I know how to "safely" store a password in the database in NodeJs and use it as a user login for example.
But know I have a different question, where I'm not sure what might be best practice.

I am using amazon product api, so I have to provide different aws Id's.
So I thought, storing them as a plain text might not be that sure, so I hashed them.

But when sending my request to the amazon Api via the code snipped below, I somehow have to safely restore the "correct key", because the hashed one will not be accepted then.

```
var opHelper = new OperationHelper({
    awsId:     'XXXXX',
    awsSecret: 'XXXXX',
    assocId:   'XXXX'
});
```

Is there some opposite way of

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update(awsId).digest('base64')
```

So to make my it more clear, how to restore a hashed key from my database so that I can use it in the amazon request again?

Or am I getting things totally wrong and I do not have to store them hashed in my database?

Thank you for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to reverse a hash without brute force.

This is the point of a hash.

Sorry

Comment: ok that is what I assumed, so I have to store the Id's as a plain text in my database or is there anyway to make it more secure?

Comment: You could encrypt them with a public key and then use a private key to decrypt.

Comment: ok I have no idea how to do that, but I will google for it ;)

Comment: Have a good read of the crypto module docs http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html and use OpenSSL to generate the keys. SO is always good when/if you get stuck